# Error: 'yaml_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to produce a summary table based on what I saw from the following link : https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/

I am following along but I keep getting the Error: 'yaml_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

#Using the trial dataset in R, I created the trial2 dataset by selecting the four variables specified
    trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, age, grade, response)

#I first tried this to produce the summary table
    table1 <- tbl_summary(trial2)
    table1

#then I tried this to produce the summary table
   trial2 %>% tbl_summary()

#and finally tried this
   trial2 %>%
    tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
    add_p()
```

all of these resulted in me getting the error message of Error: 'yaml_body' is not an exported object from 'namespace:xfun'
I have more experience with SAS then R so any help would be greatly appreciated, I tried updated all my packages and restarting R but still ran into the same problem .

Comment: I would reinstall xfun and try again?

Comment: Thank you! @DanielD.Sjoberg this worked after removing and reinstalling the xfun package. Thank you for the creation of this package it is great

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg And for me too, thanks.  Though persuaded Rstudio to let me update it was a trial.